# Why does this piece of code with two for-loops not have Big O runtime of O(N^2)?

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, time-complexity, big-o

I am learning Big O notation in my algorithms class. I just done an online quiz for this week where we get a bunch of code blocks which we have to select the big O complexity for.

I got everything correct except this code block:

```
void printPairs(int[] arrX, int[] arrY) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arrX.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < arrY.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(arrX[i] + "," + arrY[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I put in `O(N^2)` but I got it wrong which I am not sure why, there are two for-loops? And unfortunately I can not see the other options available or correct answer till the end of the week.

Comment: The runtime would be O(N²) if there was only one input, there are two here.

Comment: What are other options? could you list them also?

Comment: In general, for quick evaluation of an algorithm, I would also write it as a `O(n^2)` as well. Your lecturer decided that he/she wants you to differentiate between the different unknowns.

Comment: @PhamTrung Sorry becuase some people in the class have not taken the quiz I can only see other options and correct answer at end of week.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The runtime would be **O(N²)** if there was only one input i.e. one array passed as a parameter and iterated over in each of the two for-loops.

Because there are two inputs (`arrX` and `arrY`) for the method and both are used in each of the two for-loops.

The Big O runtime is **O(XY)** where `X = arrX.length` and `Y = arrY.length`.

**Edit:**
As stated by **[@Oighea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8242447/oighea)** This is *still* a quadratic-time algorithm. It is just in two variables.

Comment: This is *still* a quadratic-time algorithm. It is just in two variables.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the amount of elements per array, let's say `arrX` has n elements and `arrY` has m elements. The first iteration is done over `arrX`, so regarding only the first loop would have a runtime of **O(n)**.
The inner loop iterating over `arrY`, which has m elements has a runtime of **O(m)**, due to it being iterated once for every element of `arrX`, the entire method has a *worst case* runtime of **O(nm)**.
Assuming the case of both arrays having the same length, that special case would have a runtime of **O(nm)** with **n = m** and that would make it **O(n^2)**.

Your answer is not totally wrong, but it does not include all possibilities, just one...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. There ARE 2 loops. but each of the loop iterate over different arrays.

So if the length of the first array is=**N** and that if the second array is =**M**, then the worst case time complexity will be **O(nm)**

Now, if the size of both the arrays is same, n=m, then **O(nm**)**=O(n^2**)